# No suitable constructor found for type GeoJsonPoint

Tags: geojson, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest, spring-data-commons

Having a lot of trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong. Sadly I had it working at one point, but can't determine what I changed that broke it.

From what I understand this should be fully supported now.

**Object in question:**

```
@Document
public class Place {

    public final static String URI = "/place";

    @Id private String id;

    private String name;

    private String caption;

    private GeoJsonPoint location;

    public Place() {}

    public Place(GeoJsonPoint geoJsonPoint) {
        this.location = geoJsonPoint;
    }

    // Proper getters & setters clipped.
}
```

**The call** (My version of Spring Boot includes the extra x/y coords for some reason.)

```
{
    "id": null,
    "name": null,
    "caption": null,
    "location": {
        "x": 41.988161,
        "y": -87.6911499,
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            41.988161,
            -87.6911499
        ]
    }
}
```

**The Pom** (Maybe I have the wrong/clashing dependencies?)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.nestorledon.hang2gether.core.Application</start-class>

        <!-- Includes new GeoJson support. -->
        <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Fowler-RELEASE</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.M2</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test-mvc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.M2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin> 
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FINALLY got this working.

Created a custom JsonDeserializer

```
public class GeoJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<GeoJsonPoint> {

    private final static String GEOJSON_TYPE_POINT = "Point";

    private final static String JSON_KEY_GEOJSON_TYPE = "type";
    private final static String JSON_KEY_GEOJSON_COORDS = "coordinates";


    @Override
    public GeoJsonPoint deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {

        final JsonNode tree = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        final String type = tree.get(JSON_KEY_GEOJSON_TYPE).asText();
        final JsonNode coordsNode = tree.get(JSON_KEY_GEOJSON_COORDS);

        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        if(GEOJSON_TYPE_POINT.equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
            x = coordsNode.get(0).asDouble();
            y = coordsNode.get(1).asDouble();
        }

        else {
            System.out.println(String.format("No logic present to deserialize %s ", tree.asText()));
        }

        final GeoJsonPoint point = new GeoJsonPoint(x, y);

        return point;
    }
}
```

Then I just specified the a converter on the property itself.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = GeoJsonDeserializer.class)
private GeoJsonPoint location;
```

Comment: While this works, [the answer by user2088941](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56948777/3126973) is the way to go...

Answer (score 5):

GeoJsonModule works like charm :)

```
mapper.registerModule(new GeoJsonModule());
```

Comment: Haven't touched this in a long time! Hopefully the next time I revisit this it's as simple as that!

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Data MongoDB](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/geo/GeoJsonModule.java) already contain a module that can be registered in jackson to deserialize GeoJsonPoint.

To install (in spring boot) simply add to your configuration class: 

    `@Bean
    public Module registerGeoJsonModule(){
        return new GeoJsonModule();
    }`

Then you should be able to deserialize by using:

```
{
    "location":{
        "x":0,
        "y":0
    }
}
```

Comment: Will try this when I have a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Like this you can register any custom defined `ObjectMapper`:

```
@Configuration
public class HttpMessageConvertersConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
                .modules(new JavaTimeModule(), new Jdk8Module(), new GeoJsonModule())
                .build();
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper));
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, you can format text as a code with 3 symbols " ` " at the beginning of the code and 3 " ` " at the end.

Answer (score 0):

put this in a @Configuration class

```
@Bean
public GeoJsonModule geoJsonModule() {
    return new GeoJsonModule();
}
```