# ConverterNotFoundException From Double to GeoJsonPoint using MongoDB, Spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'd like to extract a ramdom data from users database

The data i need to extract is the person who is near the user who is logged in

i've already set geoSpatialIndex and insert user location data.

[image]

this is userDocument

```
@Getter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Document(collection = "user")
public class User {

@Id
private String id;

@Schema(description = "이메일")
private String email;

@JsonIgnore
private String password;

@Schema(description = "유저 상태")
private UserStatus status;

@Schema(description = "성별")
private Gender gender;

@GeoSpatialIndexed(name = "geoIndex")
@Schema(description = "로그인 당시 위치")
private GeoJsonPoint location;

public void setLocation(String latitude, String longitude) {
    this.location = new GeoJsonPoint(Double.valueOf(longitude), Double.valueOf(latitude));
}
```

At first, i used GeoResult but i figured out i needed SampleOperation because of random data.

so i made code like this

```
    @Override
public List<User> findUserLocation(Optional<User> user, Gender gender) {

    Query query = new Query().addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").ne(user.get().getId()))
            .addCriteria(Criteria.where("gender").is(gender))
            .addCriteria(Criteria.where("status").is(UserStatus.NORMAL));

    GeoJsonPoint p = new GeoJsonPoint(user.get().getLocation().getCoordinates().get(0), user.get().getLocation().getCoordinates().get(1));
    NearQuery n = NearQuery.near(p);
    n.spherical(true);
    n.inKilometers();
    n.maxDistance(12);
    n.query(query);

//  GeoResults<User> results = mongoTemplate.geoNear(n, User.class, "user", User.class);

    GeoNearOperation geoNearOperation = Aggregation.geoNear(n,"location");

    // extract one data randomly
    SampleOperation sampleStage = Aggregation.sample(1);

    TypedAggregation<User> aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(User.class, geoNearOperation, sampleStage);
    AggregationResults<User> output = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, User.class);

//   return results.getContent();
    return output.getMappedResults();
}
```

And this is Showing JSON

```
{  "$geoNear": {
"query": {
  "_id": {
    "$ne": {
      "$oid": "63c77bcf5a139c00f5e5805e"
    }
  },
  "gender": "MALE",
  "status": "NORMAL"
},
"maxDistance": 12000.0,
"distanceMultiplier": 0.001,
"near": {
  "type": "Point",
  "coordinates": [
    124.1234,
    35.1234
  ]
},
"spherical": true,
"distanceField": "location"  }}, {"$sample": {"size": 1}}]
```

but some errors came out.

About From Double to GeoJsonPoint

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Double] to type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJsonPoint]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:322) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:195) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:175) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.doConvert(MappingMongoConverter.java:1826) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.doConvert(MappingMongoConverter.java:1818) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(MappingMongoConverter.java:1337) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(MappingMongoConverter.java:1311) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$DefaultConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2371) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$ConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2174) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1936) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:638) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
```

could you please let me know how to change the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No suitable constructor found for type GeoJsonPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533390/no-suitable-constructor-found-for-type-geojsonpoint)

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko Unfortunately, that's not my question...